# error code p0335 [crankshaft position sensor] 2000 nissan maxima

Tags: engine, nissan, maxima, code

I have a 2000 maxima with 100k miles.  It has a *pending* error code `p0335`, which is for the crankshaft position sensor. The engine light is **not** on. It has 2 crankshaft position sensors and I changed both of them but nothing changed.

It sounds like a standard misfire when in park.  Car sputters & almost stalls when shifted into drive *but not in reverse*.  It stumbles terribly when starting to drive & throughout low speeds (under 30mph) while trying to accelerate. In higher speeds it is ok.  There is also a transmission code which i was able to read with an advanced scanner: it said "initial start." It didn't seam to be a real code, and a standard scanner wouldn't read it. It didn't have a number associated with it.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Thank you! would've answered earlier but took me time to figure out how to use the site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the the stumbling issue was due to a vacuum leak in the intake that was past the maf sensor so engine was getting incorrect oxygen reading which is needed to gauge proper air fuel ratio. replaced intake boot problems disapeared. However not sure if that solved the code I think it might have come back